# Can anyone let me know when to use touch-ui dialog in AEM?

Tags: aem

There are few differences between touch-ui dialog and classic-ui dialog.Pls explain the necessity to use one over the other.

Thanks
Vinuthna

Answer (score 2):

Classic UI was the Ext JS based UI for CQ5 actually until 5.6.1 
But starting with 5.6 Adobe introduced a new mobile first UI strategy.
In the course of release 6.0 and the rebranding of CQ to AEM the touch interface, which is based on Adobe's framework stack Coral UI + Granite UI (Coral UI also used for other marketing cloud products), became the new default interface technology for AEM.

Touch UI is in contrast to the ext js based classic UI, fully responsive and supports mobile as well as desktop devices. It also integrates with the UI concept for other marketing cloud products.

Adobe confirmed that classic UI is still fully supported but new features will be targeted to the new touch UI.

However touch UI is not fully on par with the functionality provided by the classic UI yet.

See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/the-basics/touch-ui-concepts.html for details about touch UI and the underlying stack.

Comment: In coral ui and granite ui difference is not clear in simple language? Is there a good reference for this?

Answer (score -1):

From: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy/best-practices/ui-recommendations.html

The following is a list of recommendations from Product Management for Adobe Experience Manager 6.1:

Project is just starting to use Adobe Experience Manager.

Recommendation: Use the touch-optimized UI per default for all users.
Be aware that some tasks still need the classic UI, but in future updates these will be done in the touch-optimized UI. See list below of available updates.

Project has used AEM for a while.
Project has used the product UI out-of-the-box and developed custom components for the sites.

Recommendation: Update to 6.1 and configure the classic UI as the default for page authoring for all users. See Selecting Your UI.

Then, in a second phase, evaluate the touch-optimized UI page authoring. The touch-optimized page authoring is able to load/use component edit dialogs originally developed for the classic UI, by loading them as-is.

Project has built a site that uses the ClientContext with integrations.

Recommendation: Update to 6.1 and configure the classic UI as the default for page authoring for all users. See Selecting Your UI.

Your sites work unchanged in 6.1 when using the classic UI for page authoring.

Project has used CQ/AEM for many years.
Project has extended the product UI (e.g Site Admin) and built components with extensive edit dialogs.

Recommendation: Update to 6.1 and configure the classic UI as the default for page authoring for all users. See Selecting Your UI..

Then start a project to apply customization and optimize component dialogs for the touch-optimized UI. See Resources to Help.

Project uses Microsoft Internet Explorer 8 as default browser (without alternative browser).

Recommendation: Update to 6.1 and configure the classic UI as the default for all users.

The touch-optimized UI requires Internet Explorer 9 or newer.